# Generate complex union type from another complex union type

Tags: typescript

I have this data structure :

```
type FirstOne = {
  type: 'first-one',
  uniqueKey1111: 1,
};
type FirstTwo = {
  type: 'first-two',
  uniqueKey2222: 2,
}
type First = {
  type: 'first',
  details: FirstOne | FirstTwo
}
type SecondOne = {
  type: 'second-one',
  uniqueKey3: 3,
};
type SecondTwo = {
  type: 'second-two'
};
type Second = {
  type: 'second',
  details: SecondOne | SecondTwo,
}
type DataType = First | Second;
```

data have type and subtype, if I select first type don't can select second-one subtype,

I have on page two select, first refer to Data.type, second to Data.details.type
I need validate select options:

I have next generic for convert type DataType to SelectOption:

```
type SelectOption<T> = { name: string, value: T };
```

I don't known how validate additional options what it's value depend of main select options

```
type SelectOptions = {
  main: SelectOption<DataType['type']>[],
  additional: SelectOption<DataType['details']['type']>[];
}

const options : SelectOptions = {
  main: [{name: 'name', value: 'first'}],
  additional: [{name: '', value: 'second-two'}],
}
```

in options now set invalid data, but typescript not check what additionalOptions have option what not compatible with main.

Also I think currently SelectOptions structure don't can exec this checking.

I will be grateful for any idea to solve the problem

I realize what options need have next structure

```
const options  = {
  main: [{name: 'name', value: 'first'}, {name: 'name', value: 'second'}],
  additional: {
    first: [{name: '', value: 'first-one'}, {name: '', value: 'first-two'}],
    second: [{name: '', value: 'second-one'}, {name: '', value: 'second-two'}]
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not said this explicitly, but I presume you want `SelectOptions` to look something like this:

```
type SelectOptions = {
    main: SelectOption<"first">[];
    additional: SelectOption<"first-one">[] | SelectOption<"first-two">[];
} | {
    main: SelectOption<"second">[];
    additional: SelectOption<"second-one">[] | SelectOption<"second-two">[];
}
```

If so, you can indeed get TypeScript to compute `SelectOptions` in terms of `DataType`, but you need to do so by *distributing* your definition across the (nested) unions in `DataType`.

Skip this next section if you just want the answer and not the explanation:

---

There are two ways to distribute across unions I know of; one is **[distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)**, where you write a type of the form

```
type D<T> = T extends any ? F<T> : never
```

, and the compiler will automatically break `T` into its union constituents before calculating; and so `D<A | B>` will evaluate to `F<A> | F<B>`.  Note that this is not easy to use *inline*; you cannot write `(A | B) extends any ? F<A | B> : never`, because `A | B` is not a type parameter.   You can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) as in

```
type DAB = (A | B) extends infer T ? T extends any ? F<T> : never : never
```

to declare a type parameter `T` and distribute across it; this works, but is more complicated and harder to explain to those unused to the intricacies of conditional types.

The other way is to use **[mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)** which you then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union of its values.  This only works if the union has some [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) key-like property in it.  Let's say the union `T` has a property named `"type"` of a literal type; then you can use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) like this:

```
type D<T extends { type: PropertyKey }> = { 
  [U in T as U['type']]: F<U> 
}[T['type']];
```

and then again, `D<A | B>` will evaluate to `F<A> | F<B>`.  This is more complicated looking, but is actually less crazy to use inline.  Here you *can* just replace `T` with `A | B`:

```
type DAB = { [U in (A | B) as U['type']]: F<U> }[(A | B)['type']];
```

In what follows I will use this latter method:

---

Here's the definition of `SelectOptions`:

```
type SelectOptions = { [DT in DataType as DT['type']]: {
    main: SelectOption<DT['type']>[],
    additional: { [DTD in DT['details']as DTD['type']]:
        SelectOption<DTD['type']>[]
    }[DT['details']['type']]
} }[DataType['type']]
```

You can see that we are distributing the operation over the `DataType` union, and for each piece `DT` of that union, we are distributing further over the `DT['details']` union.

You can verify that it evaluates to the definition at the very beginning. Let's make sure it works:

```
const badOptions: SelectOptions = { // error!
// -> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"first"' is not assignable to type '"second"'.
    main: [{ name: 'name', value: 'first' }],
    additional: [{ name: '', value: 'second-two' }],
};

const goodOptions: SelectOptions = {
    main: [{ name: 'name', value: 'second' }],
    additional: [{ name: '', value: 'second-two' }],
}; // okay
```

Looks good.  The incorrect data has now been rejected, and the correct data has been accepted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uYPej8dTmdzgBM99vOlva7rSwbTcwB76wWPvY-l-UThWBANAMigLUt1bZAti3XcKBrV88QAZQgeBkigr83n6bsoFQ5JBw6ADhAnNBp1nUUAGYdAotcNyWFC0KqODMM7bDj1wxjODPC8azo5C8KqFjuXYgTOCIoQgMwECwJ0Bj0LbcY5KYvcX3tEApIUJY1i3K0lM4aZq0Q5AUIyVDMGbGA0kYQp209cBHCQOJRAAcxHJBOieGcdGhddqy9CwAHVKGAZymVY-jTPgczLPSHgSg7HIwBA4BZIgSLoqs4A5BQdSQE0hxcwcdUlElNUx1NEBOBSTKnlS9KLMy7LcvyiBlUk6SoHVQrhzVEq1RtQxjEYrAkAoGLGHApATLMhrYqE9QktEHRJS5Q5u0OUd3M8hyT3-dwyoLSrqseDJltW+zu02jyMi8kTOO4iglX28rhCMWt3mmqLZom2zJRQaEoxyjSlnjf7upTHQEsWlKprSmbxqysGkyK3rSpeoQjoeRhaqlf6UFlJH2tAzq1VBhQUHBjUtALT6MvSbLycpvq9j+g0lSJsCuuRnq1RrDMgby-pKd5-hZgAKjNWnvuAOKwqQaG6vhxqnD-LAnD6gaaiqrHMkVr6EbkFXTyHdXSt0uH9eV1XMAe03+r58YoeSvW6espwOOSO3NcxmrTth+qDfd0SCIgO3zYD5WPaqW2Nb5sXZkM4bPzwSrpcmqWEdlrkcTMShsAAQmMHF+xUAA-cuK8rouFha48jY-JwnowT0KE-eUoDQZzQDwUybH3d4lSDzjG4AOmMBWkBWuzIHW+yru27traegwDvUH2TrO6edvnm6dqjrjz0e57eOrJOkGciguDTl206Eiep7W48Nrc67bqVffl9X4R1+xv2H4u48O8377wep-WihYFgUAANYgFsPwIAA)

---

UPDATE: the new structure is significantly different and probably deserves a different question, but I will provide the answer here without much elaboration (it's just key remapping at this point), and hope the scope of the question does not change further:

```
type SelectOptions = {
    main: SelectOption<DataType['type']>[],
    additional: { [DT in DataType as DT['type']]: SelectOption<DT['details']['type']>[] }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAEQJYwC4CcMBGArtlAIKK4D2MMAqiBlSALJTYAWVAJjCgN7AUwlBhClcAMySoAYgB4AKgD4BQkRoAeALhSL1wgL4HR4qFJkoyAlNgCecKLoBEZZymMaxE6chQAhG3tHF393TxFwaHhLTBx8AgBhZm4MbCZwABs1DQ1g1DQlVQBePRQoTVIQXhQwEDsUAH4UBRUUXRAoADdzEzyHArJA0sLrAB8A5QBuPpEAejnbAfQhlFKFMlUJhX9lEwjhKNgEPwBJEEyxKDi8QmTqtIywbMFckXyV4ZQACnGAgEpypUoNU+GJJOYys1FECqjU6g1mq1VB1upDUT1cLNhAslo5PmsWvJNihtvJdvsTEcYn4WGA4I5uDk3niCkpYSCavxWboAArURy4ewAaSgDUMJRsAG06KYymA+HQpQByfLKgC66t0CjoqkMUsUKrVmpmLNZBJGxNJk1NLNxHzQq3WxK2RIpGgOKGpJ1Q50unTpDKgTNeLIdTulsrEPz+-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-2GsqxPgd1KO9eqtaZsD+UDFTfPAHMABU5p0z9IDxeFKAw-VCNNc4-44M4-WDbU1XY1kSvfYj8iq2ew4a2VenwwbKtq9gj1mwN-MTNDKX6-TNnOJxKT21rWO1WdcMNYbHtiYRUD2xbgcq571R25r-Pi3MRkjV+BBVTLU3S4jcvcri5jULgACEJi4gOqgAH4V5XVfF4srUnsbn7OM9WBelQX4KjAGAueABBmbYB4fMqwdcU3AB0JiKygq32dAG0OddO09jbz2GIdGi+6d50z7tC+3bt0fcReT0vXxNbJygLlUDw6eu+nwmT9P60npt7k3XdyoHyva8iBvOP+4-l0Ty73fgfR6X86JFkWFQAA1mAOw-kHI0lQHQOA3ANKoEEEeBils3aywWiISemcmqC1aszdGR0dZ+yhlPAGhMWqgz4MjY0aYiEMyJiBEm3NjT9Q8JSYak0vzjSyhnHBd8EqFgfhdWez956v0Xn+bcK93JSN2i-bae9cJiXARQk6f8oaFg0DbLeT9lTAN2jbUOSibAmLMUvM8R9tFmg0AfYxgDTFyI0fdAiw4rEqKuh4kBIcHEHULIYDGHhDI1kMEAA)

Comment: I change option structure ->  const options  = {
  main: [{name: 'name', value: 'first'}, {name: 'name', value: 'second'}],
  additional: {
    first: [{name: '', value: 'first-one'}, {name: '', value: 'first-two'}],
    second: [{name: '', value: 'second-one'}, {name: '', value: 'second-two'}]
  },
}

Comment: I've updated the answer, see the bottom section.  If there are any further scope changes I strongly suggest opening a new question.  Good luck!